# Polar plot with Python changing the thickness of my grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I am working with Python 2.7 on a live plot of data, that I get from a Spectrum analyzer.

The live plot is working perfectly fine and plots the data continuously in a polar plot.

I changed the labels of my y-data which refer to the radius.

```
plt.yticks((0, 30000000, 230000000, 750000000, 1000000000, 1500000000), ( 0, '30MHz', '230MHz',  ' 0.75GHz', '1GHz', ' 1.5GHz') )
```

That will give me a grid line on every of this label.

I want to increase the thickness of these grid lines ( the dashed line)  to see them better because they are covered with color.

I hope you can help me. And if you need more code I am happy to share more of it with you.

Here is an example of my plot:

[image]

**EDIT**

Although the question is already answered (thanks tom) I want to share some useful commands with you.

I googled again and found that you can add some more keywords to grid()

```
grid( color = 'r', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 3 )
```

`color` is actually pretty obvious but with `linestyle = '-'` the line is drew through.

Comment: if you share a link to the image (on imgur, for example), someone with more rep could embed it for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this by setting the `linewidth` of `ax.grid`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121,projection='polar')
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122,projection='polar')

ax1.grid(linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To change only the concentric circles, you can set `linewidth` just for `ax.yaxis.grid`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121,projection='polar')
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122,projection='polar')

ax1.yaxis.grid(linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]